# Numerical Problems with GNU MP Bignum Library

Tags: c++, gnu, gmp

I'm doing some number crunching, which needs high precision arithmetic. I'm using the GNU MP library, and [according to the GMP manual](http://gmplib.org/manual/Nomenclature-and-Types.html#Nomenclature-and-Types):

"Floating point number or Float for short, is an arbitrary precision mantissa with a limited precision exponent."

Although the mantissa is supposed to have an arbitrary precision, I'm still running into precision problems. Rather than bore you with my actual code, here is a near-minimal working example that illustrates my problem. The code calculates 9.3^15, 9.8^15 and (9.3*9.8)^15. On my machine, the values of (9.3^15)*(9.8^15) and (9.3*9.8)^15 start to differ from the 16-th digit onwards, in this case leading to an error of (around) 4.94*10^13.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Code below.

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    mpf_class x, y, z;
    x = y = z = 1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        x *= 9.3;
        y *= 9.8;
        z *= 9.3*9.8;
    }

    std::cout << z - x*y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `9.3` and `9.8` can't be represented exactly in binary.

Comment: This only appears to be exponentiated to the power of 15, not 100.

Comment: You're right DeadMG. I was using a power of 100 but then realized that 15 is enough to illustrate my point. Edited.

Comment: @Mystical: Thanks for your comment. To be honest I don't get why you say that, but if it makes a difference, the problem still happens with 93 and 98. Those are just integers - surely they can be represented exactly.

Comment: Since `9.3` and `9.8` aren't representable in a `double`, they will keep that `+/- 10^-16` error when they are precision extended into whatever GMP precision you want. That's the main problem. If it's not working with even integers, then there's a separate issue. I suspect that you're not using the library properly, but I don't use GMP so I can't tell.

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a little girl, you people are lovely :-) Thanks for your help, everyone. In the end I have gone for the quotient method; it's significantly slower, but this is something I need to compute just once at the start of my algorithm, so it's not a problem. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is due to the fact that 9.3 * 9.8 is calculated **approximately**. Please change the literals to be instances of the mpf_class:

```
mpf_class a, b;
a = 9.3;
b = 9.8;

// ...

x *= a;
y *= b;
z *= a * b;
```

If you need **infinite** precision, consider using **rational numbers** instead:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    mpq_class x(1), y(1), z(1), a(93, 10), b(98, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        x *= a;
        y *= b;
        z *= (a * b);
    }

    std::cout << z - x*y << std::endl << z << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
0
7589015305950762920038660273144124106674963183136666693/30517578125000000000000000
```

Comment: Didn't notice that, but I see what you mean- 9.3 and 9.8 are doubles, not `mpf_class`.

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 Do you mean define: mpf_class * x = new mpf_class; ?

Comment: @Oleg2718281828 Thanks for the contribution. It does make a difference - the error is reduced to the order of 10^9. I really need it to be zero though.

Comment: That's because it still uses `9.3` and `9.8`. Remember that they are treated as `double` so they are rounded accordingly *before* they are converted to `mpf_class`.

Comment: @mga I think you need rational numbers instead of floating point

Comment: @mga If you need the two calculations to return identical results, really identical, for arbitrary exponents, you need rationals. Or for cases like this, pairs of integer significands and a bse-10 exponent would be possible, but you'd have to roll your own, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set no precision explicitly, so you get the default precision, which is usually (I think) 64 bits, thus the results differ in the last bit(s) due to different rounding in the different ways of computation. That makes roughly 20 digits the common prefix (the difference may grow much larger with more calculations). If you set a higher precision,

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    mpf_class x(1.0,200), y(1.0,200), z(1.0,200), a("9.3",200), b("9.8",200), c(0,200); 
    c = a*b;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        x *= a;
        y *= b;
        z *= c;
    }

    std::cout << z << "\n" << (x*y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << z - x*y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

200 bits here, you get a more accurate result:

```
$ ./a.out 
2.48677e+29
2.48677e+29
-4.80637e-49
```

so a common prefix of about 80 decimal digits, or nearly 256 bits (the smallest multiple of 64 larger than 199).

With a precision of 2000, the difference is -2.78942e-588 with the string constructors, 0 if initialised from `double` (but then, of course, the initial exactness is limited to 53 bits, so that just means that both ways accumulate the error in the same way).

Comment: I believe the `a = 9.3;` still needs to be changed. Perhaps it will accept `a = "9.3";`. Though I can't find a list of assignment operator overloads in the documentation.

Comment: Even if I have `a(9.3,200), b(9.8,200)` in the declaration, the output remains the same. Using a string in the constructor is actually worse.

Comment: hmm... lack of documentation on the precision behavior of GMP sure doesn't help. Once thing for sure is that you can't use floating-point literals unless they're exactly representable.

Comment: Ah, duh, I forgot to set `c`'s precision :(

Comment: Come to think of it, this particular example passes because it's using the same (incorrect due to `double` round-off) value of `9.3` and `9.8` for both computations. If the result were compared with a different library they'd still only have about 16 digits of accuracy. If GMP doesn't accept strings as arguments, then you'd pretty much have to manually do a division by 10 at full precision.

Comment: It does accept strings as arguments, and the result is the same as for initialising with integers and dividing by 10. You're right of course that initialising with doubles limits the overall exactness to the first 53 - accumulated error bits, but with `c = a*b` both ways of calculation share the same error except for the last few bits.